# Find max value of previous day, second previous day from moving window using bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a requirement to find the max value of the previous day (val_prev_day), the second previous day (val_sec_prev_day
), third previous day (val_third_prev_day) from the corresponding list of raw values (val_raw) for each day as shown in the below example.

[image]

Comment: what is the schema of your table? not clear from image in your question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select day, val_raw,
  max(val_raw) over(prev_days range between 1 preceding and 1 preceding) val_prev_day, 
  max(val_raw) over(prev_days range between 2 preceding and 2 preceding) val_sec_prev_day, 
  max(val_raw) over(prev_days range between 3 preceding and 3 preceding) val_third_prev_day, 
from your_table
window prev_days as (order by unix_date(day))
```

if applied to sample data like in your question - output is

[image]

P.S. I used below dummy data to test above

```
with your_table as (
  select date '2022-01-01' as day, 0 as val_raw, union all 
  select '2022-01-01',  10, union all 
  select '2022-01-01', 110, union all 
  select '2022-01-02',  30, union all 
  select '2022-01-02',  70, union all 
  select '2022-01-02',  90, union all 
  select '2022-01-03',   0, union all 
  select '2022-01-03',   5, union all 
  select '2022-01-03',   5, union all 
  select '2022-01-04',   0, union all 
  select '2022-01-04',   5, union all 
  select '2022-01-04',  10 
)
```

Comment: have you tried?

Comment: Yes, It works perfectly fine as per my requirement. Thank you so much. Performance of the query is also good

Comment: Sure. Thank you so much once again.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming dataset schema, but basically you can `shift days` in the `subqueries` and do `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

```
WITH
dataset AS (
    SELECT           1 as day,   0 as val_raw,
    UNION ALL SELECT 1 as day,  10 as val_raw,
    UNION ALL SELECT 1 as day, 110 as val_raw,
    UNION ALL SELECT 2 as day,  30 as val_raw,
    UNION ALL SELECT 2 as day,  70 as val_raw,
    UNION ALL SELECT 2 as day,  90 as val_raw,
    UNION ALL SELECT 3 as day,   0 as val_raw,
    UNION ALL SELECT 3 as day,   5 as val_raw,
    UNION ALL SELECT 3 as day,   5 as val_raw,
    UNION ALL SELECT 4 as day,   0 as val_raw,
    UNION ALL SELECT 4 as day,   5 as val_raw,
    UNION ALL SELECT 4 as day,  10 as val_raw,
),
shift_one_day_max AS (
    SELECT day + 1 as day, max(val_raw) as max_val,
    FROM dataset
    GROUP BY day
),
shift_two_day_max AS (
    SELECT day + 2 as day, max(val_raw) as max_val,
    FROM dataset
    GROUP BY day
)
SELECT *
FROM dataset
LEFT OUTER JOIN shift_one_day_max USING (day)
LEFT OUTER JOIN shift_two_day_max USING (day)
;
```

[image]

c.f. I omitted `event_ts` since it's not affecting the operations.

Comment: Solution if fine. But it very costly query in terms of performance. Thank you